# Prevent click event being triggered on children elements

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I don't understand why when I add a click event listener on an element, its children triggers it too.

I want that the parent is triggered even if the children are clicked, which should be the normal behavior I think.

Here's the code :

```js
var jobsList = document.querySelectorAll('.job_list .job');

for (var i = 0; i < jobsList.length; i++) {
  jobsList[i].addEventListener('click', _onChangeJob, false);
}

function _onChangeJob(e){
  
  // When The children (.job_title, .job_date) is clicked, this function is called. I want only the parent to be clicked event if the children are clicked.
  
}
```

```html
<div class="job_list">
  <div class="job active" data-job="1">
    <p class="job_title">Job</p>
    <p class="job_date">21.11.16</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job active" data-job="1">
    <p class="job_title">Job</p>
    <p class="job_date">21.11.16</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to check what has been clicked, then for example check if the `jobsList` collection contains the target element. If it does then one of the `.job` elements is the target, otherwise the target is a child element.

```
// convert to a regular array to get indexOf method
var jobsList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.job_list .job'));

for (var i = 0; i < jobsList.length; i++) {
  jobsList[i].addEventListener('click', _onChangeJob, false);
}

function _onChangeJob(e){
  if( jobsList.indexOf( e.target ) !== -1 ){
    console.log( 'clicked on .job')
  }
  else {
    console.log( 'clicked on a child element')
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4r7hLua2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just realised while I was reading it that what I needed was currentTarget and not target. So my problem is resolved with e.currentTarget. Sorry for your time and thank you !